# Delegating constructors - use () or {}?

Tags: c++11, constructor, delegates

I have a constructor that delegates to another constructor.
The only question is that can I use {} instead of () when I call the Base constructor?
Derived class is sub-class of the Base class.

```
Derived::Derived(double amount, int _int_rate): Base(amount), int_rate{_int_rate}{}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, why you shuldn't?